# iOS enumerate json remove objectkey

Tags: ios

I'm struck how to enumerate JSON by remove first object in iOS programming as below
**From**

```
[{"001": {"name":"test", "url":"test"},"002":{"name":"test1", "url":"test1"},"003":{"name":"test2", "url":"test2"}}]
```

**to**

```
[ {"name":"test", "url":"test"},{"name":"test1", "url":"test1"},{"name":"test2", "url":"test2"}]
```

Pls help to recommend me or suggestion coding.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
NSArray *jsonArray = //parsedJsonArray
NSDictionary *values = [jsonArray objectAtIndex:0];
NSArray *valuesArray = [values allValues];
```

And the `valuesArray` will contain the data in format,

`[ {"name":"test", "url":"test"},
{"name":"test1", "url":"test1"}, {"name":"test2", "url":"test2"}]`

Answer (score 0):

You can easily convert a json string to a NSMutableArray :

```
NSError *error;

// Get a NSMutableArray from the json string 
NSData *data = [yourJsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSMutableArray *arrayResult = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];

// Remove the first object
[arrayResult removeObject:[arrayResult firstObject]];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jsonDataArray1=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[JSON objectForKey:@"001"]];
jsonDataArray2=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[JSON objectForKey:@"002"]];
jsonDataArray3=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[JSON objectForKey:@"003"]];
jsonDataArrayFinal=[[NSMutableArray    alloc]initWithObjects:jsonDataArray1,jsonDataArray2,jsonDataArray3 nil];
initialize all above arrays in viedidload
```